# List separators' weird lines before the text

Tags: uitableview, swiftui, list-separator

Can’t seem to figure this thing. In my list, I have these white (black in dark mode) lines before the text, which I fail to get rid of. Somebody told me that this means that I coded something wrong. But what is it? Here’s my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

init(){
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}

var body: some View {
    
    List {
        Text("List Item 1").listRowBackground(Color("customColor"))
        Text("List Item 2").listRowBackground(Color("customColor"))
        Text("List Item 3").listRowBackground(Color("customColor"))
        Text("List Item 4").listRowBackground(Color("customColor"))
        Text("List Item 5").listRowBackground(Color("customColor"))
    }.background(Color("customColor"))
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
    }
}
```

And then in the appDelegates (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) I put in this:

[image]

```
UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .darkGray.
```

Found several topics about list background colors but in those nobody seems to care about these annoying lines. What do I do to get rid of them?

Comment: Wow, something went wrong! The [![enter image description here][1]][1] doesn't belong here. I tried to add a picture to my question. How do I update the question?

Comment: There is no such effect with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

Comment: Isn't the 11.6 the most current one though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SwiftUI 2.0**

No changes needed - works as-is

**SwiftUI 1.0+**

Here is a fix (tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4)

```
UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear    // << add this one !!
UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Asperi! It worked. As for your previous comment about the Xcode 12. I tried to update it on the AppStore, and it told me that I have the most current one (11.6). What am I missing here? Or should I buy a new MacBook to get the Xcode 12?

Comment: No, you don't need new MacBook :D... it is beta, you can download it from developer.apple.com if you want (it is enough to have free account there)